# TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type while applying a selfmade Bernoulli fitting on a list

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-fitting, bernoulli-probability

I'm trying to implement my own Bernoulli class with its own fit function in order to fit my train and test lists that contains words (spam detection)

here's my Bernoulli class:

```
class BernoulliNB(object):
    def __init__(self, alpha=1.0):
        self.alpha = alpha

    def fit(self, X, y):
        count_sample = len(X)
        separated = [[x for x, t in zip(X, y) if t == c] for c in np.unique(y)]
        self.class_log_prior_ = [np.log(len(i) / count_sample) for i in separated]
        count = np.array([np.array(i).sum(axis=0) for i in separated]) + self.alpha
        smoothing = 2 * self.alpha
        n_doc = np.array([len(i) + smoothing for i in separated])
        self.feature_prob_ = count / n_doc[np.newaxis].T
        return self

    def predict_log_proba(self, X):
        return [(np.log(self.feature_prob_) * x + \
                 np.log(1 - self.feature_prob_) * np.abs(x - 1)
                ).sum(axis=1) + self.class_log_prior_ for x in X]

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.argmax(self.predict_log_proba(X), axis=1)
```

And here's my implementation:

```
nb = BernoulliNB(alpha=1).fit(train_list, test_list)
```

Expected result:

Been able to fit with my class my train and test lists
But instead I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

on the following line:

```
 count = np.array([np.array(i).sum(axis=0) for i in separated]) + self.alpha
```

I don't know why it fails though, maybe due to the fact that I have lists instead of np? not even sure how to fix it.

Can someone help me or explain to me how to achieve the fitting?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error message by apply `sum` to a structured array:

```
In [754]: np.array([(1,.2),(3,.3)], dtype='i,f')
Out[754]: array([(1, 0.2), (3, 0.3)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
In [755]: _.sum(axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-755-69a91062a784> in <module>()
----> 1 _.sum(axis=0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)
     34 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     35          initial=_NoValue):
---> 36     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)
     37 
     38 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I'm guessing your error occurs in

```
np.array(i).sum(axis=0)
```

and that `i` produces, or is a structured array.

I can't recreate your run just by reading your `fit` code.  You'll need to run it with some diagnostic prints (focus on shape and dtype).  A general observation, when running `numpy` code, never assume that you got things like shape and dtype right.  Verify!